# Sieve of Eratosthenes in C# with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, sieve-of-eratosthenes

Can someone look over this [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) implementation? It seems almost too easy.

Rather than maintaining a seperate `bit[]` to track prime/not prime, I'm just removing the noncandidates from the collection completely on each iteration.

**Pseudocode**

```
LIST = 2...n

set M = 1
while M < sqrt(n)
   set M = next number in LIST > M
   remove all multiples of M (excluding M itself) from LIST
```

**C#**

```
int cur = 1, total = 1000;
var pc = Enumerable.Range(2, total).ToList();

while(cur <= Math.Sqrt(total))
{
    cur = pc.First(i => i > cur);
    pc.RemoveAll(i => i != cur && i % cur == 0);
}

Console.WriteLine(pc.Max());
```

It just seems a bit too easy. Results seem right though. In [LINQPad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LINQPad) 4

- Runs `total = 100000;` in 0.008 secs
- Runs `total = 1000000;` in 0.141 secs
- Runs `total = 10000000;` in 2.973 secs

Comment: Nobody mentioned this in their answers, but `Math.Sqrt()` isn't the quickest of functions, and the return value used here is effectively constant.  Remove it from the comparison, and assign the results to a local variable instead (which can be used in the comparison).  I do _not_ believe the compiler is smart enough to catch this... it wasn't when my flatmate tried this.

Comment: @X-Zero: Yes, the sqrt calculation should naturally be moved out of the loop. I already tried that, and it makes very little difference for the performance, so I just went for simplicity/close to original code in the answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it works, but it's slow.

I compared it to this:

```
bool[] notPrime = new bool[total];
notPrime[0] = true;
notPrime[1] = true;
for (int i = 2; i <= Math.Sqrt(notPrime.Length); i++) {
  if (!notPrime[i]) {
    for (int j = i * 2; j < notPrime.Length; j += i) {
      notPrime[j] = true;
    }
  }
}
```

(I used `Enumerable.Range(2, total - 2)` in the Linq code to make it produce the numbers 2 to 99999 rather than 2 to 100001.)

For total = 100000, average for 100 executions:

```
Linq 27.696966 ms., 0.280000 collections
Array 0.708616 ms., 0.030000 collections
```

So, it takes a lot of time, and does more garbage collections.

Comment: one question - wouln't it be faster to skip the even values? after you had `i=2` you can skip `4,6,8,10,..` by repalcing `i++` with `i+=2` from 3

Comment: @fubo: It might be faster, but it's not certain as the code gets more complicated. After the first iteration all the even items in the array has already been set, so all those will be caught in the `if` statement in the loop. Actually, the principle of the sieve is to weed out all multiples but for all numbers, not just two.

Comment: I've tried it and there was a minor improvement - however how about changing `bool[]` to `System.Collections.BitArray` ? .NET uses one `byte` to store a `bool`ean value. I've tried `total = 1.000.000.000`and have a memory usage of 120MB with  `System.Collections.BitArray` and 976MB with `bool[]`

Comment: @fubo: Accessing the data in the `BitArray` is slower, but fewer memory cache misses will make it faster, so that could go either way. If it uses too much memory you can just do multiple sieves. For each sieve you just initialise it by masking out the multiples of the prime numbers that you got this far.

Comment: Looking at the implementation in this answer vs. the sudo code. The sudo code says j should start at i^2, but this code starts at i*2. Should the second for loop be this?
 for (int j = i * i; j < notPrime.Length; j += i).

Answer (score 1):

**update:** as tested and explained by @Guffa and @EoinCampbell, this is actually **much slower**.

The benefits of a `HashSet` are mainly in access speed by index.
Since the algorithm never even accesses the list by index, the `Hashset` will merely introduce additional overhead with the hashing and storing of the internal structure for fast access.

---

I would user `HashSet<int>` instead of `List<int>`.

The only change needed would be in the while, `.RemoveWhere()` instead of `.RemoveAll()`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb361254.aspx

Comment: I tested that, and it takes twice as long as using a list...

Comment: Hmm... interesting but it actually makes it significantly slower...

for 10000, 100000, 1000000 the times were

List = 8ms, 140ms, 3s
HashSet = 30ms, 700ms , 15s

Comment: I did not test it (#CaptainObvious) 
 Wow, it takes **so** much longer?!? My universe of coding assumptions is destroyed. :(

Comment: @ANeves: As you are looping the items in the hash set to remove them and not removing them by value, you don't get any benefit from using a hash set.

Comment: @Guffa ... of course, I see now. Never even accessing them by value (get/set/remove), we are actually hashing all of that for nothing. Oh, I should edit the answer. [does]

Answer (score 1):

You're accessing modified closures in your LINQ statements, so I'd copy them to locals.

```
        var cur = 1;
        const int Total = 1000;
        var pc = Enumerable.Range(2, Total).ToList();

        while (cur <= Math.Sqrt(Total))
        {
            var cur1 = cur;
            var cur2 = pc.First(i => i > cur1);

            pc.RemoveAll(i => i != cur2 && i % cur2 == 0);
            cur = cur2;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(pc.Max());
```

Comment: Could someone run speed tests on this? [very curious]

Comment: Negligible on my test system.  For 10000000, the average difference over 10 runs was 26ms.

Comment: Wouldn't declaring `cur1` and `cur2` properly outside the while loop improve memory usage?

Comment: No.  They're local variables.  Matters not where you declare them.

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer on Stack Overflow a few days ago.  I adapted it a bit to make it more parallel and easier to read.

I might have made a mistake.  I tested it in my computer: Core i7 Second Gen (3GHz) with 12GB of RAM.

It took a few seconds to solve most of the numbers less than 50,000,000. However, it took around 6:32 seconds to solve 100,000,000.  It took around 47 mins to solve 500,000,000.  It crashed 11 hours after solving 1.5 billion.

```
private static void GetPrimeNumbers(int max)
{
    var allPossibleNumbers = Enumerable.Range(3, max-3);
    var possiblePrime = allPossibleNumbers
            .AsParallel()
            .Where(n => Enumerable.Range(2, (int)Math.Sqrt(n))
                                  .All(i => n % i != 0)
            )
            ;
    possiblePrime
            .ToArray()
            .AsParallel()
            .Dump()
            ;
}
```